# Xcode launches but does not run programs

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, launching-application

I have a weird problem with launching and running a C program in XCode. I create a command-line C program (the program just prints "Hello, World!\n"). The program is complied with no problem. How it does not print any output in the Debugger Console window when I run it (using the Run item in the Run menu).

I run XCode under my admin account, so there should not be problems with admin rights required to run XCode Debugger under non-admin accounts. The weird thing is that if I log in to another admin account (created for testing), then I have no problem running the program from within XCode: I see the line "Hello, World." as well as GDB's output.

I suspect that there's something wrong with my account (not the one created for testing), as I changed my account's shortname before. I would greatly appreciate it if someone here can give a glimpse of the problem and/or a possible fix.

Solutions that I have tried: using Disk Utility to repair permissions; using dscl to add me to the _developer group (but I don't think it actually helped as my account is admin); and reinstalling XCode.

My laptop is running OS X 10.6.8, and the version of my XCode is 3.2.6.

Comment: try putting a while(1) at the end, it might be running and closing the console, otherwise look for a console tab in XCode, it would be running there.

Comment: Try: NSLog(@"Hello, World!\n"); To get Hello World in the Debugger

Comment: Thanks, but I think the problem probably is GDB is not running. I open the Console window (using the Run menu), but there's no program's output. I see only lines like

[Session started at 2013-01-30 04:27:02 +0100.]

and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that XCode Debugger hangs on my machine is that there is .gdbinit in my home directory that points to a GDB version different from that in XCode. I remove .gdbinit and the Debugger works again.